# promises sequence combination with Q

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I wanted to **create dynamically** a sequence of promise dynamically passing its result to the next promise.

So I did this (took this from the documentation)

```
this.actions.reduce(Q.when, Q());
```

where this.actions is an arrray of functions which return promises. [f1,f2,f3]. This is working well we have a nice dynamically created promise sequence.

What I want to do now is a little bit more complicated and can't find how to do it (however I believe it's possible, i'm just missing something here).

I would like to be able to create the same things but with several promises executing at the same time (something with q.all I guess)
Here is the explanation:
this.actions = [f1,[f2,f3],f4]

f1 is executed and it's result is passed to both f2 and f3.
f2 and f3 are executed simultaneously and both results are passed to f4 when both done
f4 is executed and can use f2&f3 results

So we have a sequence of promises just like the first example but some elements of this sequence can be group of promises passing all their results to the next elements of the sequence (another promise or group of promises).

I guess it's not really hard to do but I'm a bit confused how to build this.

thanks a lot!

Comment: That makes no sense. A promise is not an action that can be executed or to which something can be passed, it's a result. So what is that `this.actions` array really?

Comment: Well it's an array of function which returns promises. Is my problem not clear ?
p1 => api call => get a result .then((result) => { p2(result) } ...
and so on, when a promise of the sequence is done the next promise is taking its result.
I apologize if it's unclear let me know where I can make it clearer.

Comment: That's ok, but then you shouldn't write "*where `this.actions` is an arrray of promises.*" and name them `p1`, `p2` etc.

Comment: ok but do you see what's my problem here ? I mean is it understandable ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm already writing an answer…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
f1().then(x => Q.all([f2(x), f3(x)])).then(f4)
```

or, if writing the chain as a reduction sequence,

```
[f1, x => Q.all([f2(x), f3(x)]), f4].reduce(Q.when, Q())
```

To programmatically build the function that runs `f2` and `f3` concurrently, you can use

```
function concurrently(fns) {
    return x => Q.all(fns.map(fn => fn(x)));
}

[f1, concurrently([f2, f3]), f4].reduce(Q.when, Q())
```